# How to generate a -5V to +5V sine wave from one DC supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, sine

I need to generate a -5V to +5V sine wave, the only supply I can use is one battery upto 12v. I need to be able to adjust the frequency with a potentiometer. Output current needs to be a minimum of 100mA. Two bonus features would be to be able to adjust the amplitude and offset with two additional pots. Frequency range needed is around 60-600Hz

I have tried to do some research on my own but am struggling with the correct terminology as I'm only a hobbyist with little experience in analog electronics.

I don't expect someone to come up with a complete design for me (but that would be a bonus of course!) but just to help with a starting point, some terminology that I am lacking or some reference sources.

Comment: What frequency range is needed?

Comment: 60-600hz, question updated.

Comment: Start with 12V (> 10) rather than 9. Build a suitable oscillator : Wien bridge, phase shift, whatever. Add a current output stage (or use an IC power amplifier) for 100 mA. AC couple to output.

Comment: There are DC to DC converters, for instance unipolar 12 V to bipolar +- 12 V. +- 10 V will do too.

Answer (score 1):

This design should help you a good way on towards your aim although it won't provide the full +&- 5V, maybe +& -4V. I chose the common op amp for its rail to rail output capability and low input bias currents.

It's a Wien Oscillator followed by a variable gain power stage.

R6 & R7 linearise the J-Fet.

[image: Wien Oscillator & Power Stage]

EDIT

This bootstrapping technique should get you up to +&- 5V. I've split the output transistors' base resistors and added the capacitors.

[image: Adding Bootstrap to power stage]